# Passing data from one fragment to another through activity - Lag between

Tags: java, android

I have a tabbed interface that has two fragments (one for each tab). Once I leave one of the tabs I want the data input there to be passed to the other tab. However there seems to be error when using these methods in my main activity:

```
public void setAddresses(String[] addr)
{
    addrArray = addr;
}

public String[] getAddressArray()
{
    if(addrArray == null)
    {
      return null;
    }

    //Else return the array
    return addrArray;


}
```

One fragment is sending data using setAddresses via it's `onPause` method and 
the new tab/fragment that is selected is retrieving the data using it's `onResume` method.

However there seems to be some sort of lag between these fragments. When going to the new fragment `getAddressArray` returns `null`, but if I force it to call it's `onResume` method again then `getAddressArray` (correctly) returns an array. How can I avoid this split second lag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain circumstances where onPause/onResume won't get called at all. A ViewPager is an example, as the pages either side of the visible page are kept in an active state. I'm not 100% sure if this applies to tabs as I've not used them for ages, but it may be the case.

The approach for communication here is not really correct and a better way to do it would be to use a listener to communicate changes up to the activity, then for the activity to communicate relevant changes back down to other fragments.

Refer to this page in the docs for more info: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: So basically have a listener for my UI widgets to pass the data to the activity as often as possible?

Comment: Well, be careful not to spam your activity with callbacks, but at least when relevant events are triggered within your fragment it might be a good time to populate changes up to your activity.

Answer (score 1):

The correct and good way as explained in the [SDK Article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

**1.Activity-to-Fragment**

The host activity can deliver messages to a fragment by capturing the Fragment instance with **findFragmentById()** or **findFragmentBy()**, then directly call the fragment's public methods.
your Fragment can easily check if parent Activity implements this interface, so Fragment will be able to communicate its needs,

**2.Fragment-to-Activity**

To allow a Fragment to communicate up to its Activity, you can define an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during its onAttach() lifecycle method and can then call the Interface methods in order to communicate with the Activity.

Read the [SDK article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for detailed Example